# when i use Kafka Streams , I am very confused, how should I specify the offset of topic-partition for consumption?

Tags: apache-kafka, offset, apache-kafka-streams

for example .i have a topic "test" with 4 partitions .when i start the stream app, And after some time, the app crashes.I want to specify the offset for consumption，i want to consume data from offset after last reading.
But I can't find anything that can help achieve it using kafka-streams api.

P.S. We are using kafka-2.1.0

Comment: If you have specified a groupId and automatic offset committing then just restarting the streams will pick up where they left off.

Comment: Thank you, I understand what you said. It may be that I described it incorrectly. Specifically, I want to store the topic-partition offset to an external component such as redis at the end of each consumption. Then every time I consume, I query the topic-partition offset from redis and start the consumption by the topic-partition offfset I specified.

Comment: Kafka Streams doesn't expose that. You would have to use the Consumer API before the Streams app started / stopped to get/set offsets. Kafka Streams isn't (currently) meant to interact with services external to Kafka